# Writing rendered image to file (C++)

Tags: development

I am trying to modify a little bit the source code of blender to fit it to my needs. Does anybody know which function is responsible for saving a rendered image to file?
Thanks in advance.

What I would be interested in is how to invoke the whole 'saving image' procedure, which is called for example after every frame in rendering an animation. I just want to call such a function in the process of rendering.

Comment: Have a look into `source/blender/imbuf` to add a new format and `source/blender/editors/space_image/image_ops.c` to edit how blender saves the image. Also [this old diagram](https://www.blender.org/bf/codelayout.jpg) from the [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Blender_Source/Files_Structure) should help. You can also try the official [IRC channel](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Community:Chat).

Comment: Are you sure you need to go as deep as source code? I've made loads of post-render things using python and app handlers https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.app.handlers.html

Comment: Those handlers might be a solution, unfortunately, I don't know how to save currently rendered image from handler call. When I use function bpy.ops.image.save() I get the error: RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.image.save() failed, context is incorrect. Any help?